# Print case find empty parameter

Tags: angularjs

How to display a message if the parameter is empty ?
I have a variable " parameters":{}, where I check if it has variables . If you separates the ng -switch . I need you to print a message " no data " if he finds the " parameters":{}.

```
<div ng-repeat="p in ctrl.currentreport.parameters" ng-switch="p.dataType">

                        <div ng-switch-when="Integer">
                            <reportinteger parameter="p"></reportinteger>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="DateTime">
                            <reportdate parameter="p"></reportdate>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="Boolean">
                            <reportboolean parameter="p"></reportboolean>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
<div ng-hide="Object.keys(ctrl.currentreport.parameters).length">No data</div>
```

Wherever you want

EDIT: even better

```
<div ng-show="angular.equals({}, ctrl.currentreport.parameters)">No data</div>
```

Comment: The message "No data" appears when you have data, it would appear when he had not .